# Will this create NullPointerException , if not why not?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have this below lines of code

```
String name = null;
if (something)
    name = someString;
if (name != null && name.equals("XYZ"))
    doSomethingWith ("hello");
```

Will the above if condition result in NullPointerException , if "something" is false ?
if not why not ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it won't. The `&&` operator in Java is a [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) one so, if `name` is `null`, then `name.equals()` will not be executed (since `false && anything` is still `false`).

Same with `||` by the way: if the left hand side evaluates to `true`, the right hand side is not checked.

Comment: just curious, what is the opposite to short circuit evaluation called? Is there any other language which implements such behavior, where the above stated problem could have thrown a NPE?

Comment: Wikipedia says "eager evaluation" (follow that link I gave) but I've never heard that term in this context. I would have said "greedy" since that's the term used in regular expressions for taking the largest match rather than the shortest. Looks like Fortran does it, and Pascal may do it. The Visual Basic variants also don't short circuit although they seem to provide a _means_ to.

Comment: I have seen instances where they call it the NON-short-circuit operator :)

Comment: Or long-circuit. Actually, since it comes from the world of electricity, perhaps we should call it the full-circuit operator.

Comment: Pascal doesn't do it. In VB.net you can choose, they introduced a special operator for it (and vs. Andalso, or vs. Orelse). Similar in Smalltalk, where class Boolean has different methods for short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @Dirk, that link states that ISO Pascal leaves it open as to whether the standard `and/or` will short-circuit, and there's an extension which gives guaranteed short-circuit versions.

Comment: @zengr Eiffel has two operators "AND" and "AND THEN". AND is evaluates both operands, AND THEN short-circuits. http://tecomp.sourceforge.net/index.php?file=doc/lang/basic.txt#chapter_6

Comment: @pax thanks for the update. My last experience was with Turbo Pascal 6, where the default behaviour was complete evaluation, but you could turn short-circuit on using a compiler option.

Comment: @Dirk: It works in Java too if you use the binary operators `|` or `&`. They are... non-short-full-circuit-eager.

Answer (score 2):

No It wont. The Right Hand Side of **&& operator** gets executed only if the Left Hand Side of **&& operator** is true.

Similarly in case of **|| operator** , if the Left Hand Side is true , the Right Hand Side will not be executed.

Comment: RHS = Right Hand Side, LHS = Left Hand Side.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't cause a NullPointerException, because of how the `if` statement is written.  You have:

```
if ( name != null && name.equals("XYZ")) {
    //do stuff...
}
```

The conditions in the `if` statement are evaluated from left to right.  So if `name` is null, then the `name != null` condition evaluated to `false`, and since `false && <anything>` evaluates to `false`, the `name.equals("XYZ")` condition never even gets evaluated.

This behavior is a [runtime optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) that avoids executing code that cannot affect the result of the `if` statement, and it just so happens to also prevent your example code from ever generating a NullPointerException.